# How many wisps are summoned for the barbarian spirit totem?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, barbarian

I'm having trouble finding where it says how many wisps the *Spirit Totem* rage powers summon around their barbarian, or whether it even matters.  Do they each make their own attack, or do all the wisps together just make one attack?  If they do each make their own, how many are there?

Reference: [PFSRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/coreClasses/barbarian.html#spirit-totem)

Comment: I reworded your question because multiple questions in a single "question" are often closed, but your questions were rather related and deserved to be a single question.  If you're not happy with it, you can rollback my edit by clicking the little [edited X time ago](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/53353/revisions) over my name, or simply edit it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They make one attack collectively, so no, their exact number doesn't matter.

Although note that the *Greater Spirit Totem* rage power causes the wisps to do 1d8 (with no bonuses, but also no need to make an attack roll or save) negative energy damage to every enemy adjacent to the barbarian, *and* still make their "wisp attack" against any one foe within 15 feet, which could be one who already took the automatic damage or not.  In addition to granting the barbarian concealment against enemies any further away than adjacent...  if you have a Cha-based barbarian for whatever reason (rage mage?  tribal leader?  noble scion in need of anger management?), the powers look pretty good.

Comment: Okay, this does make sense. Thank you for the clarification!